# php variable not passed a value

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
foreach($rec as $rk => $r){
    $parrecid = 0;
    $id = 0;
    if ($rk=='PARENT_RECORD_ID'){
        echo $rk . ' = ' . $r . '<br>';
        $parrecid == $r;
    }
    if ($rk=='ID'){
        echo $rk . ' = ' . $r . '<br>';
        $id == $r;
    }

}
    echo 'pushing id = ' . $id . ' parrecid=' . $parrecid . '<br>';
    array_push($arrobj, $id, $parrecid);
```

In theory when $rk = 'PARENT_RECORD_ID, the $parrecid value is supposed to get populated.
Same case for $id, if $rk = 'ID' then... you get the picture.
However, that never happens. Both values remain 0. 
Any ideas why?

Comment: `==` is for comparing, `=` is for setting. `Use $parrecid = $r;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take the initialization of $parrecid and  $id out of the loop.
Second , dont use == to put a value into a variable. `$parrecid = $r;` instead of `$parrecid == $r;`
Your code should look like this:

```
$parrecid = 0;
$id = 0;

foreach($rec as $rk => $r){
    if ($rk=='PARENT_RECORD_ID'){
        echo $rk . ' = ' . $r . '<br>';
        $parrecid = $r;
    }
    if ($rk=='ID'){
        echo $rk . ' = ' . $r . '<br>';
        $id = $r;
    }

}
```

Comment: Strange thing:
If i use = then the if condition is true for every value?!?!
If i use == then it's true only for the specified value?!!?!

Comment: @user117701, for if condition you have to use == otherwise it wont work. To put a value into a variable you use = . Yep , at the start it seems strange but you will get use to it, a hurdle for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

At first, use `=` for assignment as mentioned in other answers.

Second thing is, after you set your `$parrecid` and `$id` in your loop, you do not stop you loop immediately, so you also overwrite them again in the next loop run with: `$parrecid = 0; $id = 0;`, and they are `0` again.

One solution would be to set the variables outside the loop:

```
$parrecid = 0;
$id = 0;
foreach($rec as $rk => $r){
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is not a matter of overriding the value as much as a complete scope failure. Anything declared inside the for loop is not readable outside it.

Comment: If the scope is wrong, why is this working: http://codepad.org/xw5OjVLW see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php What you mean would be right in Java, but not PHP

Answer (score 1):

Your variables $parrecid = 0; and $id = 0; are defined withing the for loop so the updated value won't be readable unless they are defined prior to for loop, and use correct assigning (= instead of ==) operator when assigning values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` for assignment instead of `==`.  Also, declare those variables outside the `foreach` loop, because otherwise they will be reset on each invocation of the loop.